# Amazon Product API return Amazon.com price or lowest price or both

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon Product API. During API requests I am using this response group:

```
Images,ItemAttributes,Offers,OfferFull,OfferSummary,SalesRank,Variations
```

I get the new lower price however I do not get the Amazon.com offered price. For example, if you see the price of this ASIN `B00NCSIN4W`. You will see that Amazon.com offered price is more than the price offered by another merchant for the new item.

Is there any way to get the lowest new price offered by amazon.com and another merchant at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResponseGroup: **ItemAttributes, Offers**
Version: **2011-08-01**

**Lowerst price offered by merchant**

```
<OfferSummary>
<LowestNewPrice>
    <Amount>9448</Amount>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
    <FormattedPrice>$94.48</FormattedPrice>
</LowestNewPrice>
<LowestUsedPrice>
    <Amount>6999</Amount>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
    <FormattedPrice>$69.99</FormattedPrice>
</LowestUsedPrice>
<TotalNew>14</TotalNew>
<TotalUsed>25</TotalUsed>
<TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
<TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
</OfferSummary>
```

**Just below, lowest new price offered by amazon.com**

```
<Offers>
    <TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
    <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
    <MoreOffersUrl/>
    <Offer>
        <OfferAttributes/>
        <OfferListing>
            <OfferListingId/>
            <Price>
                <Amount>9899</Amount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                <FormattedPrice>$98.99</FormattedPrice>
            </Price>
            <AmountSaved>
                <Amount>100</Amount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                <FormattedPrice>$1.00</FormattedPrice>
            </AmountSaved>
```

And then you can read from XML

Comment: That's lowest new price is marketplace new price that may or may not equal what's currently offered by Amazon.

Comment: @nicholasnet what about offers tag, I see price is offered price with saving amount too?

Comment: @nicholasnet I tried couple of products with scratchpad and it seems to work fine? Offer price is priced offered by amazon itself whereas <OfferSummary> has lowest price, isnt it?

Comment: No, as far as I know they could be different. If you pass condition all. In few hours I will post more detail.

Comment: You were right I must have over looked something. Thank you.

Comment: @nicholasnet sure :-)